# In Angular, method always returning error state—even when executed correctly

Tags: angular

Using this method in Angular, when I try to delete an object in the SQL Server:

```
public deleteCourse(){
    this.courseService.deleteCourse(this.courseId).subscribe((c) => {
        alert('course deleted!');
    }, (err) => {
        alert(err.message);
    });
}
```

The method works fine and the course is successfully deleted, but it will always show the:

```
alert(err.message);
```

Instead of:

```
alert('course deleted!');
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Probably the back-end server is sending a error response because the request lacked something. Could you please show the `deleteCourse()` function implementation?

Comment: What is the error message you're getting ?

Comment: @DeleteMapping("delete/{courseId}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteCourse(@PathVariable int courseId){
        courseService.deleteCourse(courseId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("course deleted!");
    }

Comment: and this is from the facade class

Comment: public void deleteCourse(int id){
        courseRepo.deleteById(id);
    }

Comment: the message i get in the alert is: [Object Object]

Comment: @michaelD  i dont think its the back end server because in swagger i get status of 200 and the message "course deleted!" i attended..

Comment: also this is the method in the course.service.ts in angular:   public deleteCourse(courseId: number): Observable<Course>{
    return this.httpClient.delete<Course>('http://localhost:8080/delete/' + courseId);
  }